# Can we use Numba in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, numba

I'm building a Flask App that analyzes data. I want to use *Numba* to speed up the algorithm. I have tried on the algorithm with *Numba* and it works perfectly in the Jupyter Notebook.

However, when I try the code in the Flask app, it fails. It seem likes it cannot access to the function that binds with `@numba.jit`. Is that means that we cannot use *Numba* in a Flask app?

Comment: can you provide the error which you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Numba within a Flask application (I do). The issue sounds like the environment that you are launching Flask from is different than the environment that you are running your Jupyter Notebook from. From within your Flask app, you could try printing the `sys.path`.

Comment: I checked on the command prompt it shows that it detects NumbaWarning, is it the reason it fails to work?

Comment: I can't really tell what is going on without minimally seeing the traceback that your code produces.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operations you perform on the functions. you can perform array and other computation operations which was supported by Numba. Structure your code accordingly to utilize Numba functions.

Comment: The answer is correct; however it is unlikely that the bottleneck in a flask application lies in "array and other computation operations". The questions is leading most likely to the wrong direction.